# ViewChild of script tag returns undefined

Tags: html, angular8, viewchild

I need to access a script tag with ViewChild but it returns undefined when I try to access to `nativeElement`. It is working with a normal `<p>` tag but not with `<script>` .
[Here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-viewchild-example-kts1yj) with an example (with `p` and `script`).
I basically do:

```
@ViewChild('pRef', {static: false}) pRef: ElementRef;
```

and the in ngAfterViewInit():

```
this.pRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = "DOM updated succesfully!!!";
```

Comment: Having scripts in your views is usually a bad practice. What exactly you want to do ? is script tag necessary to have there ? why you cant use any other html tag ? Just help us to understand the requirement so that we can help

Comment: @TechnoTech I receive a string from server and I have to insert it inside a script tag because it's js code, so that the page can execute it. I can't save it as a local file because the browser needs user interaction

Comment: That means your requirement is to add script tag in html template dynamically. Checkout my answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

User Renderer2 and Document to inject your script dynamically.

in app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild('pRef', {static: false}) script: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('prefworking', {static: false}) prefworking: ElementRef;
  constructor(
        private _renderer2: Renderer2, 
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document
    ) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.prefworking.nativeElement.innerHTML = "Working pref"; 
    this.convertToScript();
  }

   convertToScript() {
         let script = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
        script.type = `text/javascript`;

        this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
    }
}
```

I have created the stackblitz. checkout this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-viewchild-example-gaffzs

Comment: But this way I see the script inside the page. I need to include the script in the page to execute it, but not see it.   
Like using `<script src="../../../assets/js/myScript.js"></script>` but receiving it from the server, so it isn't static